# Irradiance Measurement of Incandescent Lamps

Tags: radiometry

I have two spectroradiometers that use the same detector from two different manufacturers an Oceaan Optics FX and a Gamma Scientific GS1220.  They each have their own cal lamps.

After calibrating the FX I can measure the absolute irradiance of that lamp and it looks great, just like the cal file.  When I measure the GS1220 lamp with the FX the the curve is not "smooth" there is sort of a knee in the 700 to 750 nm range.  The peak irradiance is pretty close to the cal for the lamp.

Could this be because the FX cal lamp has a color temp of 2800K and the GS1220's is 2600K?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the root of the problem lies in the different reflectance properties of the two lamps holders and interfaces to the integrating sphere.
[image]